# How do I increment a value at a given time of day?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am developing a system for a hotel where the days value is incremented at 12:00hrs each day.

Example A: When a customer checks in at 10:00 on Monday, I need the system to start counting from 12:00 on Tuesday.

Example B: When a customer checks in at 15:00 on Monday, it will start counting from 12:00 on Tuesday.

Comment: You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Majid-Alaeinia, I will try with Carbon.

Comment: Clarified a few details.  Feel free to correct if my assumption of 24-hr clock is mistaken